# Method triggered by Change in orientation

Tags: iphone, ios

Is here a way to run a method when the iOS devices orientation changes?

I would like to change only some objects orientations on the screen, and not others.

What delegates do I use etc.

Cheers
-A newbie

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Depends when you want to react:**

If before rotation, **override** from UIViewController:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
 // do something before rotation
}
```

If you want to perform something after rotation:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
 // do something after rotation
}
```

**Reference:**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

Comment: These methods have been deprecated.

Comment: Deprecated in iOS 8.0

Answer (score 6):

`UIDevice` posts `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`

`UIApplication` posts `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` and has a related delegate callback for each.

`UIViewController` receives several orientation related calls triggered by the UIDevice notification if the view controller is part of the controller hierarchy managed by a window.

If you are already using a UIViewController, implement some of the orientation related methods, otherwise register for the UIDevice notifications.  The most important UIViewController method is `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` because if that return `NO` the others are not called.

Comment: I prefer to register as an observer to receive the orientation notifications. So I vote up this answer.

Answer (score 0):

willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: is the method you are possibly looking at. Read up on that one.

Answer (score 0):

[`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s are sent [`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a) just before rotation, and [`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation%3a) after rotation.

To configure additional animations, use either [`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a) or [`willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a), [`didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation%3a) and [`willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a). The latter are used for two-step animations, which you generally use when you have header or footer views that are moved offscreen for the main transition animation.

Answer (score 0):

My sandbox app:
https://github.com/comonitos/programatical_device_orientation

The solution is easy:

in interface (h file) :

```
BOOL rotated;
```

in implementation (m file):

1. rewrite

   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
   {
       return rotated; 
   }

2 call [self setup]

```
-(void) setup 
{
   rotated = YES;
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
   rotated = NO;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing much more than to tell the OS if you support an orientation change in the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.  Plus, this is deprecated in iOS6.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: yep. now it is. from that time i'm transforming views

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code snippet to check the orientation changes.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect as `viewWillTransitionToSize` will still print portrait in this case when there is a transition from portrait to landscape.