# Creating UIViewController's with subview programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to create a controller which has a UIWebView as a subview programmatically. I manage to do it with the following code:

VLUpdateViewController.h

```
@interface VLUpdateViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView* webView;

@end
```

VLUpdateViewController.m

```
@implementation VLUpdateViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];

    NSArray* constraints = [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[webView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"webView" : self.webView}] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[webView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"webView" : self.webView}]];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

However, my problem is that the webView doesn't resize properly when the orientation changes. In fact, it doesn't resize at all. it just rotates at the cent of the screen.

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

I tried omitting `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` but I got the following result when i changed the orientation to landscape.

[image]

Comment: You will need to update UIWebview's frame when orientation changes. and update constraints as well.

Comment: There is no problem when I'm doing it on the storyboard, and the correct answer for that question doesn't work for me.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar How could I do that?

Comment: @halileohalilei check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4301828/1679187

Comment: Why did you people marked this as a duplicate? Did you even looked at the proposed answer? That's NOT the answer to this question! This one is asking for a programmatical approach.

Answer (score 1):

I copy and pasted your code, and added the missing line:

```
self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

You had translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO for your self.view but not your self.webView.

### Final code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];



    // ---------------------------------------
    // this line is missing
    // ---------------------------------------
    self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;



    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];

    NSArray* constraints = [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[webView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"webView" : self.webView}] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[webView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"webView" : self.webView}]];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I only get a black screen and the webpage is not loaded.

Comment: Something else is interfering then, is that the real code you pasted? It seems like you're using a custom view controller, perhaps your view controller's view isn't loaded immediately. In that case, try delaying your constraint setup and web page loading until after view did appear. See if that helps.

Comment: I'm creating this controller from another UIVIewController and presenting it modally with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. Might this be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

The most easy way to using Autolayout is [Masonry](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry)..Instead of writing multiple lines of code, this will make the work done pretty perfectly.

Add Masonry framework (preferably pod) and import the class.
and use this piece of code :
// the below line states that the webview should have the same size of the superview at any state

```
[self.webView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(superview);
}];
```

and if you like to have some padding:

```
UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

    [self.webView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(superview.mas_top).with.offset(padding.top); 
        make.left.equalTo(superview.mas_left).with.offset(padding.left);
        make.bottom.equalTo(superview.mas_bottom).with.offset(-padding.bottom);
        make.right.equalTo(superview.mas_right).with.offset(-padding.right);
    }];
```

and voila .. this is so much it.